# Code analysis tool for Visual web developer 2005

Tags: c#, code-analysis

I am currently doing a project in **Visual Web Developer 2005 Express Edition**. It is written in C# and the target browser is IE6. (these are requirements of the client)

The client is very strict when it comes to coding and comment standards. We have to strictly follow the standards that they have created. Thus, I would like to know if there is a tool that checks if we have followed the standards.

I have tried **CodeMaid** and **StyleCop**. For CodeMaid, it is only working for Visual Studio 2008 and not in Visual Web Developer 2005. For StyleCopy, it is not working for both.

Any suggestion would be great.

EDIT:
As suggested in the comments, a standalone program is also ideal for this situation.

Comment: The implied VS2005 integration complaint seems pretty severe considering it is a 10 year old product; who is going to be building tools for that?  Why don't you ask for a style checking tool that doesn't have to run in VS2005, e.g, runs as a standalone program?

Comment: If at all possible, I would consider upgrading. You can still target IE6 and use old versions of ASP.NET from more modern IDEs.

Comment: @IraBaxter Do you have any suggestions of a standalone program for this task? Thank you for the response :)

Comment: @svick What would be the minimum version of Visual web developer that would support static code analysis?

Comment: @roberto:  I think you should recast your question to look for standalone style checkers.  Be sure to check out SR's guide for good questions.  (I don't have any specific ideas; I just thought you constrained the solution so hard there would be no answers).

Comment: Did you ask the client if they use any tools in-house and, if so, which?